# How to set X axis range on plotly graphs?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using R version of plotly. Here is what I want:

```
x = 1:100
y = 1:100
plot_ly(x, y)
```

I want the graph only show where x>20 and x<40, ignoring the other part. How to do this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the `layout` of `xaxis`.

```
y = 1:100
plot_ly(x=~x, y=~y) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      range=c(20,40)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to set only one range value like in ggplot's xlim(20,NA)?

Comment: If you'd like, replace `range=c(20,40)` with `rangemode='tozero'` and you'll have the range extend down to zero without having to specify an upper limit. potentially a good idea depending on your data and use case.